# filter multi dimension array python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, filter

I have 2 array. From marks, I want to filter elements in an array which its value less than 5. And credits will be filtered with list of index filtered from marks.
Input:

```
 marks = ([[8.0, 9.0, 10.0],
       [4.0, 9.0, 8.0],
       [8.0, 3.0, 8.0],
       [10.0, 9.0, 5.0],
       [9.0, 9.0, 4.0]])
 credits = ([2,2,1])
```

Output:

```
marks_2 = (
       [[8.0, 9.0, 10.0],
       [9.0, 8.0],
       [8.0, 8.0],
       [10.0, 9.0, 5.0],
       [9.0, 9.0]])
```

credits will be filtered with indexes has been filter from marks_2 when compare with each rows on marks.

Is there any solution using numpy instead of using loops?
thank you.

Comment: Can you better explain how the values in `credits` are generated?

Comment: it's value will be input from users, but its  length equal with each row from marks

Comment: Show the working loops solution

Comment: in `marks_2` you have a 4.0 in the second array, I don't understand what filter values less than 5 means then

Comment: @UlisesBussi sorry, my mistake,
edited the question

Comment: it's okey! i had dee doubt, i'm trying some stuff, don't have an answer yet. but can I ask why you're trying to use numpy for this?

Comment: yes, just want to try some practices on numpy. instead of loops on big array

Comment: @UlisesBussi
The solution using loops over array:
```
for scores in marks:
        condition = scores >= 5
        score_pass = scores[condition]
        subject_pass = credits[condition]
```

Comment: Hi i've been thinking a lot and couldn't get a solution avoiding loops. I think numpy trend to work everything as n-dimensionals arrays with fixed shape (matrices in this case). the best I can offer you right now is a one-liner `score_pass = [scores[scores>5] for scores in mark`

Comment: @UlisesBussi, thanks for your efforts, I also get my solution from using loops.
Thank you again,